# Repeat the array element two times in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I was writing a code in JavaScript to just repeat the array element two times. Here is my code.

```
var arr = [1,2];
for(var i=0;i!=arr.length;i++)
{
  arr.push(arr[i]);
}

for(var i=0;i!=arr.length;i++)
{
  console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

For example for **arr =[1,2 ]** output should be **[1,2,1,2]**;

But I am getting error as:**FATAL ERROR: invalid array length Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory**

Comment: After you push into an array its length grows.

Comment: As is often the case, if you step through the code in the debugger, looking at the values of things and how the code moves from statement to statement, the reason becomes clear. More: [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Debugging is **not** an advanced skill. It's basically the next thing you should learn about after "Hello, world."

Comment: btw, one line alternative `arr = [...arr, ...arr]`

Comment: What's your question? Why you get the error? Or are you asking how to do it in other ways? Please always be sure to be clear and focused about the question you're actually asking.

Comment: Any other solution such as using arr.concat, or spread syntax is getting downvoted, not sure why.

Answer (score 4):

`arr.length` grows while you're pushing new elements into the array. You can store the length in a separate variable:

```js
const arr = [1, 2];
for(let i = 0, length = arr.length; i != length; ++i)
{
  arr.push(arr[i]);
}

for(let i = 0; i != arr.length; ++i)
{
  console.log(arr[i]);
}
```